# Can "it wasn't" be replaced with "not" in most situations?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Examples:

> **It wasn't** that we didn't care about the dog.
>
> **Not** that we didn't case about the dog.
>
> If **it wasn't** for the help she got from her church, she'd probably be
>   on the streets.
>
> If **not** for the help she got from her church, she'd probably be on the
>   streets.

Can I safely do this and don't change the meaning or mess up the grammar of sentences? Are there cases where I can't do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the "it" refers to some object, it can't be lost:  "After he shot the bear, it wasn't moving", but *"After he shot the bear, not moving".

The versions with "it wasn't ..." are sentences, while the versions with "not ..." are not sentences.  Therefore, in a syntactic context that requires a sentence, you won't be able to do the replacement.

Some examples:

After a verb taking a sentential complement: "It was time to leave, but John insisted that it wasn't" but *"... insisted that not". (This example is better without "that".)

Coordinate conjunctions connect phrases of the same category, so when you have a sentence on one side of "and", you have to have a sentence on the other side, too: "It wasn't the grapes, and it wasn't the crackers that shocked us" but *"Not the grapes, and it wasn't the crackers that shocked us".

Answer (score 1):

Your first pair of examples is actually a counterexample: "It wasn't that we didn't care about the dog" is a complete sentence, whereas "Not that we didn't care about the dog" requires something further in the same sentence, usually a clause linked using *but*:

> - [OK] It wasn't that we didn't care about the dog, but that we had more urgent obligations.
> - [OK] Not that we didn't care about the dog, but we had more urgent obligations.
> - [OK] It wasn't that we didn't care about the dog. It was simply that we had more urgent obligations.
> - [NOT OK] Not that we didn't care about the dog. We had more urgent obligations.

Your second pair of examples, however, is fine. (But note that many speakers would prefer "If it *weren't* for", especially in writing and formal speech.)